# Synchronize access to mutable fields with Kotlin's map delegation

Tags: kotlin, delegates, thread-safety, synchronized

Is this implementation safe to synchronize the access to the public fields/properties?

```
class Attributes(
    private val attrsMap: MutableMap<String, Any?> = Collections.synchronizedMap(HashMap())
) {

    var attr1: Long? by attrsMap
    var attr2: String? by attrsMap
    var attr3: Date? by attrsMap
    var attr4: Any? = null
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mostly.

Because the underlying map is is *only* accessible via the synchronised wrapper, you can't have any issues caused by individual calls, such as simultaneous gets and/or puts (which is the main cause of race conditions): only one thread can be making such a call, and the Java memory model ensures that the results are then visible to all threads.

You *could* have race conditions involving a *sequence* of calls, such as iterating through the map, or a [check followed by a modify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use), if the map could be modified in between.  (That sort of problem can occur even on a single thread.)  But as long as the rest of your class avoided such sequences, and didn't leak a reference to the map, you'd be safe.

And because the types `Long`, `String`, and `Date` are immutable, you can't have any issues with their contents being modified.

That *is* a concern with the `Any` parameter, though.  If it stored e.g. a StringBuilder, one thread could be modifying its contents while another was accessing it, with hilarious consequences.  There's not much you can do about that in a wrapper class, though.

By the way, instead of using a synchronised wrapper, you could use a [`ConcurrentHashMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/java.util.concurrent.-concurrent-map/), which would avoid the synchronisation in most cases (at the cost of a bit more memory).  It also provides many methods which can replace call sequences, such as [`getOrPut()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html); it's a really powerful tool for writing high-performance multithreaded code.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to edit my answer in another chrome tab, but missed it. Rolled it back.

Comment: @gidds thank you so much for your detailed explanation.